# Get radius of city or country

Tags: angular, search, geolocation

I have list of products that have longitude and latitude of places where they are selling. I want to add input with geo-autocomplete to my search bar, where if user writes the name of country he would be able to see all products that have lng and lat of cities or streets in that country. Is there any api that returns the radius of the place, besides it lng and lat?

Comment: Yes, it's called a Google Maps platform. You even have a component that does just that. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-google-places-autocomplete). Make sure you read Google Maps API's, and set up your own key beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Google places api return viewport points, so if take difference in max and min, you will get approximate radius of place